# Speech Synthesis based on a multi-person corpus

Tags: text-to-speech, voice

As a part of a project, we want to do experiments with synthetic voices where these do not have a singular geographic origin, body, age or gender. We have our own data-set, but I thought of during initial experiments with VCTK and build a voice using Tacotron2 or something similar. Does anyone know if a similar project has been done? Where the physical body that we imagine connected to a voice is intentionally ambiguous. Or other projects where TTS has be trained on a multi-person corpus? Additionally, does anyone know of any caveats or potential problems in terms of this approach? Maybe there could be ways of working with transfer-learning that could be beneficial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://github.com/r9y9/deepvoice3_pytorch

Multispeaker samples are [available](https://colab.research.google.com/github/r9y9/Colaboratory/blob/master/DeepVoice3_multi_speaker_TTS_en_demo.ipynb) as well as pretrained model you can try.